# next and previous with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a page with some bootstrap card and i want to show the card one by one without reloading the page

```
<div class="card mt-2" id="card-b">
   ...
   <button type="button" id="to-c" class="btn btn-info">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="card mt-2" id="card-c">
   ...
   <button type="button" id="to-d" class="btn btn-info">Next</button>
   <button type="button" id="to-b" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
</div>
<div class="card mt-2" id="card-d">
   ...
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
   <button type="button" id="to-c" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
</div>
```

my card body code is quite long so i paste it with dots

i already tried using hide and show like this in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#card-c').hide();
        $('#card-d').hide();

        $('#to-b').click(function() {
            showB();
        })

        $('#to-c').click(function() {
            showC();
        })

        $('#to-d').click(function() {
            showD();
        })


        function showB() {
            $('#card-b').show();
            $('#card-c').hide();
            $('#card-d').hide();
        }

        function showC() {
            $('#card-b').hide();
            $('#card-c').show();
            $('#card-d').hide();
        }

        function showD() {
            $('#card-b').hide();
            $('#card-c').hide();
            $('#card-d').show();
        }

});
```

its work fine when i click next button but the previous button doesn't work

Comment: The problem is that you have duplicated `id` . They should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it more complicated than necessary by making it all dependent on IDs when you can make one generic event listener for all and use some traversals like `next()` and `prev()`

```js
$('.btn-next, .btn-prev').click(function(){
    const $btn = $(this), 
          isNext = $btn.hasClass('btn-next'),
          $card = $btn.closest('.card').hide();        
      
          
    const $nextCard = isNext ? $card.next() : $card.prev();       
    $nextCard.show()

});
```

```css
#toggle-cards .card:not(:first-child) {
   display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-cards">

<div class="card mt-2" >
   <h3>One</h3>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="card mt-2" >
    <h3>Two</h3>
   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-next">Next</button>
   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-prev">Previous</button>
</div>
<div class="card mt-2" >
    <h3>Three</h3>
   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-next">Next</button>
   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-prev">Previous</button>
</div>
<div class="card mt-2" >
    <h3>Four</h3>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info  btn-prev">Previous</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate ids in the HTML code **id="to-c"**. You need to give a unique id to each element. So as per your code, you can change the id from this **id="to-c"** to **id="to-e"** in the last section.

```
<div class="card mt-2" id="card-d">
   ...
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
   <button type="button" id="to-e" class="btn btn-info">Previous</button>
</div>
```

and add the js code like

```
$('#to-e').click(function() {
   showC();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

lets make it simple.

just focus all **.card** elements and make **array** of **.card elements**.  **(global)**

and store **currentCardIndex** as counter. **(global)**

then add classname to next buttons as **".btnNext"**, and prev buttons to **".btnPrev"**

the logic is,

when someone clicks **button.btnNext** => currentCardIndex **increasing** and showing **currentIndexedCard** up also hiding the others.

when someone clicks **button.btnPrev** => currentCardIndex **decreasing** and and showing **currentIndexedCard** up also hiding the others.

if **currentCardIndex** value is equals to listOfCard's lenght it means **you are in last card** and do some stuff.

also when someone in **first card**, and tries to go previous, your currentCardIndex value equals to 0 and **he/she cant go prev any more.**

here is my logic and code. ( i added first card to previous button)

have fun.

```js
  // List of .card elements;
      const cardList = $(".card");
      let currentCardIndex = 0;

      setFirstCard = function () {
        // setting ONLY First Card to Visible
        $(cardList).not(":eq(0)").hide();
      };

      goNextCard = function () {
        currentCardIndex++;
        if (currentCardIndex == cardList.length) {
          alert("last card, you can submit NOW");
          // your submit code of your form etc..
        } else {
          $(cardList)
            .show()
            .not(":eq(" + currentCardIndex + ")")
            .hide();
        }
      };

      goPrevCard = function () {
        currentCardIndex--;
        if (currentCardIndex < 0) {
          alert("this is FIRST CARD, you can't prev any more!");
          return;
        } else {
          $(cardList)
            .show()
            .not(":eq(" + currentCardIndex + ")")
            .hide();
        }
      };

      $(document).ready(function () {
        setFirstCard();
        $(".btnNext").click(goNextCard);
        $(".btnPrev").click(goPrevCard);
      });
```

```html
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mt-2">
      This is Card Number 01
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnNext">Next</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnPrev">Previous</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card mt-2">
      This is Card Number 02
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnNext">Next</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnPrev">Previous</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card mt-2">
      This is Card Number 03
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btnNext">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnPrev">Previous</button>
    </div>
```